# Generating a public and private PGP Keys in Scala

Tags: scala, bouncycastle

I am using bouncy castle library in my scala project and I wrote the following code

```
def generateKeyPair(config: PGPKeyInput) : Unit = {
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())
  val kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC")
  kpg.initialize(config.numOfBits)
  val kp = kpg.generateKeyPair()
  val out1 = new FileOutputStream(s"${config.filename}-private.bpg")
  val out2 = new FileOutputStream(s"${config.filename}-public.bpg")
  val sha1Calc = new JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build().get(HashAlgorithmTags.SHA1)
  val keyPair = new JcaPGPKeyPair(PublicKeyAlgorithmTags.RSA_GENERAL, kp, new Date())
  val publicKey = keyPair.getPublicKey()
  val signerBuilder = new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder(publicKey.getAlgorithm(), HashAlgorithmTags.SHA1)
  val secretKeyEncryptionBuilder = new JcePBESecretKeyEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.CAST5, sha1Calc).setProvider("BC").build(config.passphrase.toArray)
  val secretKey = new PGPSecretKey(PGPSignature.DEFAULT_CERTIFICATION, keyPair, config.username, sha1Calc, null, null, signerBuilder, secretKeyEncryptionBuilder)
  secretKey.encode(out1)
  secretKey.getPublicKey.encode(out2)
  out1.close()
  out2.close()
}
```

This code works and I get a public and private key file but the content is all binary.

The way I want to create the public and private key files are that they start with

```
"-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\nComment: GPGTools - https://gpgtools.org\n\nmQINBFp8jgIBEAC02oIv4ohWCy79/ksR4FhagDtV13a60Ca9N2NDgAd7WNRfx5e4\nr6Eqr0m3pinyPzqEyWQc2isa9/LL/Wlb3sBaOIbWtZtmQxlugqa9NaPVYahBkVeg\nT50IfD4wzURodrjYijp2gN5H4Qu1Tcgjxo=\n=hp34\n-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----"
```

what change should I make to the code so that I get keys in the format specified above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`ArmoredOutputStream`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/bcpg/ArmoredOutputStream.html) class. You can include the optional headers as well if you want.

It should be as simple as wrapping out1 and out2 with:

```
val out1 = new ArmoredOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(s"${config.filename}-private.bpg"))
val out2 = new ArmoredOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(s"${config.filename}-public.bpg"))
```